# Nested telnet in python - Telnet within telnet

Tags: python, nested, telnet

I am trying to automate a process wherein I would telnet to RouterA and from that RouterA I would again telnet to RouterB. I have the code to telnet to RouterA and its working perfectly fine but I am not able to telnet from RouterA to RouterB. The session becomes unresponsive. I am doing something wrong. Can someone please guide me?

```
Below is my code:

import os
import telnetlib
import re

def telNetCall():
 host  = "15.xx.xx.xx"
 user  = "admin"
 password = "password"
 enable_password = "enable_password"
 telnet  = telnetlib.Telnet(host) 


 telnet.read_until('Username: ', 3)
 telnet.write(user + '\r')
 telnet.read_until('Password: ', 3)
 telnet.write(password + '\r')
 telnet.write('enable' + '\r\n')
 telnet.write(enable_password + '\r\n')
 telnet.read_until("#")
 telnet.write("telnet 20.xx.xx.xx" + '\r\n')
 telnet.read_until('Username: ', 3)
 telnet.write(user + '\r')
 telnet.read_until('Password: ', 3)
 telnet.write(password + '\r')
 telnet.write('enable' + '\r\n')
 telnet.write(enable_password + '\r\n')
 telnet.write("show logg"+ "\r\n")
 telnet.write('exit' + '\r')
 a = telnet.read_all() 
 f = open(host, 'w')
 f.write(str(a))
telNetCall()
```

Code is working but it is taking very long time to execute. I believe I am doing something which is not allowing the code to run efficiently. If there are any issues with the code suggestions are welcome. Any help is greatly appreciated.

***I have figured out the error and now its working fine for me. It hardly takes 5 seconds now.***

Comment: Why are you often sending just carriage-return, and not cr-lf? And have you tried to do this manually? Is the output as you say it should be in your script?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I can manually telnet to RouterA and from there I can telnet to RouterB. It is working fine. Its just not happening via script.

Comment: I recently found out that the code actually works. Only thing is that it takes around 8-9 minutes to complete the execution. That means I am doing something which is not correct. Mainly it is taking lot of time in executing last 5 commands. If anybody can throw some light on it I would be very grateful.

Comment: You might want to add that as an edit to your question, as that will bump it onto the front-page again.

Answer (score -1):

You can use another read_xx() functions like `read_until()` or `read_eager()`.

See comment of `Telnet.read_all()` below:

> Read all data until EOF; block until connection closed.